# How to differentiate $\frac{Z}{I-Z}(\frac{Z}{I-Z})^T$ if $Z$ is a matrix?

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives

If a square matrix $Z$ is a function of a real parameter $x$, how can one find the following derivative:

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{Z}{I-Z}\left(\frac{Z}{I-Z}\right)^T  \right],
\end{equation}
where $T$ is the transposition operation.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Can you find the derivative of $Z(I-Z)^{-1}$?

Comment: Notation $\frac{A}{B}$ should be avoided for matrices because it can be $AB^{-1}$ or $B^{-1}A$... In this precise case it is not harmful because $A$ and $B$ commute...

Comment: @HansEngler, I am not sure if the usual product rule applies for matrices.

Comment: @seeker, work it out for an arbitrary component of the product.

Comment: Hint: Let $\,Y=Z(I-Z)^{-1}$ and let a dot to denote the derivative wrt the $x$ parameter, then $$\dot Y = (I+Y)\,\dot Z\,(I-Z)^{-1}$$
Your proposed function is $F=YY^T,$ now calculate $\dot F\;$